# How to make simplified equation from summation problem

Tags: calculus, summation

Hi I have a problem to derive this one into simplified equation.  I have formula like this

$$a = \sum_{n=1}^{K}n\left(\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}\rho^n$$

I try to use geometry equation but it does not work. Could anyone solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean for your index to be $i$, or $n$?

Comment: I'm sorry it's n...my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints/Sketch: First rewrite this as
$$
a = \rho\sum_{n=1}^K n\left(\frac{\rho\gamma}{2}\right)^{n-1}.
$$
Then use the identity (for $x\neq1$)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^K nx^{n-1} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^{K+1}}{1-x}.
$$